# Angular js animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have simple demo  and need help in animating it.  Can you pls provide some help?

[Here is demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ukmDLmLo7rZgWuutn4U)

Here is code:

```
      var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

      function SimpleController($scope) {

          demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController)

          $scope.customers = [{
              name: 'Element  1111 '
          }, {
              name: 'Element 222 '
          },

          ];


          $scope.swap = function (index) {

              var temp = $scope.customers[0].name;
              $scope.customers[0].name = $scope.customers[1].name;
              $scope.customers[1].name = temp;


          }

      }
```

On cell click , I swap the elements. I would like to provide animation to show that element 111 is moving to another cell and element 222 is moving during swap.

Any pointers ?

Comment: The elements aren't moving in the DOM, their innerHTML are just changing. Is this what you want, or do you want the elements to actually move?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to hookup when the innerHTML changes in a way that shows that some change is happening for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive that watches the element's innerHTML and performs an animation everytime it changes:

```
app.directive('animateInnerhtmlChange', ['$animate', 
  function ($animate) {
    return {
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var cssClass = 'myClass';

        var unbind = scope.$watch(function () { return element[0].innerHTML; }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue === oldValue) return;
          $animate.addClass(element, cssClass, function () {
            $animate.removeClass(element, cssClass);
          });
        });

        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          unbind();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Note that I have referenced `angular-animate.js` and included the `ngAnimate` module as a dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/EoarYfk4j1VV9bst663n?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for providing information . The problem that I described was a subset of the actual animation that I am trying to solve.  I bind to an array of customers with name and image. Lets say I have 3 name and image collection. When I click on an image , I reconstruct the array of customers, so that the clicked customer image moves to the center . Thus I wanted to provide animation so that it feels like the clicked image is actually moving to the center , but behind the scenes databinding kicks in and the UI is refreshed .

Comment: Well, I answered based on the information provided in the question. Hard to guess that the use case is something else :) Please either post a new question with the actual use case, or update the existing one.

Comment: sure, here is the plunkr  , unfortunately I do not know how to add images or create image folder with some images in plunkr. But i have updated the source code.

Comment: Here is the update Plunkr , although I added some animation it does not seem to work .

Comment: Here is the update Plunkr with some animation code but it does not work http://plnkr.co/edit/kYtzM9d0rzGmrniybz9c?p=preview

Comment: I answered the new question you posted. Please remove this question if it's not what you are asking for, or accept the answer if you feel it's answering what you asked for :)